# CakePHP 3 default json decode request data doesn't work

Tags: php, json, cakephp

CakePHP documentation says:

> Typically REST applications not only output content in alternate data formats, but also accept data in different formats. In CakePHP, the RequestHandlerComponent helps facilitate this. By default, it will decode any incoming JSON/XML input data for POST/PUT requests and supply the array version of that data in $this->request->data.
>   [source](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html)

But my `$this->request->data` is empty array.

In `AppController.php` I load `$this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');`

That's my RequestHandler debug info

[image]

My request data:

`Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json`

```
{"store_id": 671}
```

And my request data always is empty, why?

Comment: how looks your request url?

Comment: just post data through `GET` and check it they are empty or not.
Ex: `http://localhost/URL?key=test`

Comment: request url: `http://localhost/MenuItems/add`

Comment: this problem occurs only if request is in json or xml

Comment: are you create ajax view /MenuItems/ajax/add.ctp ? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: no, why? It's no needed

Comment: When you say "_my request data_", do you mean that this is what you have sent, or that this is what your app receives, and you know because you've debugged that? Also where exactly in our app are you testing `$this->request->data`?

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't read POST data if it's in JSON format by default.  I'm not familiar with CakePHP, so I can't help there, but the way I typically handle it is:

```
$JSON = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo $JSON['store_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug info is from isAuthorized. in that event JSON data in available only by 
`$this->request->input('json_decode');`